# One Time Pad chat application with large random keyfiles

Tags: c#, encryption, random, cryptography

I'm just about to build a simple chat application using One Time Pad.
I've already made the algorithm, and to encrypt the messages, I need some sort of key material that is the same on both sides. The distribution of the key material is supposed to happen with physical contact (e.g. USB dongle). So I would like to make some very large random key files, that the two clients can use to communicate. So my questions are:

- I need a very secure random number/string generator, do you know any good ones that I can use in C#?
- And how do I, when I use such big files, avoid to load the whole file into memory, as I plan to read a chunk of the key material (e.g. 1 MB), and remove it from the file afterwards when read, so the same key won't be used twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Should probably start with this: I assume this is a for fun or for exercise project - not an attempt to create something truly secure.

1. As [owlstead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10939993/5542) says: Use [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library./system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider).
2. Removing the used key material from the file is much easier if you use it in reverse. If you need to encrypt 1024 bytes, read the last 1024 bytes from the file and truncate it. Simplified:

```
byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plain){
  using (FileStream keyFile = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
  {
    keyFile.Seek(-plain.Length, SeekOrigin.End);
    byte[] key = new byte[plain.Length];
    keyFile.Read(key, 0, plain.Length);    
    byte[] encrypted = new byte[plain.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<plain.Length;i++){
      encrypted[i] = (byte) (plain[i] ^ key[plain.Length - 1 - i]);
    } 
    keyFile.SetLength(keyFile.Length - plain.Length);   
    return encrypted;
  }      
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've now made the randomness generator. Now it's time to test your code!

Comment: Your code works like a charm! I had to add a (byte) cast, but other that that, it works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve an issue that has already been solved: using AES is almost certainly as safe as using the One Time Pad. In that case your key becomes 16 bytes (although you will need a NONCE or IV depending on the mode).

1. You need to use a secure random number generator [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library./system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
2. Read the file into memory using [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).

Just (atomically) store the offset in the file instead. E.g. use the first 8 bytes in the same file to store an ulong type, so you can sync when needed. You may write zero's in the file in addition to that for the bytes used if you really want. Note that e.g. with SSD's you may not actually overwrite the physical data.

Comment: Note that you might want to think of a smart scheme to update & sync the offset as well as making sure that the key data is overwritten, especially in the case of failures.

Comment: I can't seem to find out how the MemoryMappedFile works. Can you show me how to use it with strings, e.g. reading a 1 MB chunk and then delete it? (Zero it out)

Comment: You should not use character strings. Try the `CreateViewAccessor` to specify offset and size and simply write 00h bytes to the created view. As said, this is not completely safe, but it's probably the best you can do at file access level.

Answer (score 0):

What you have designed is almost certainly not a One Time Pad.  The generation of large quantities of truly random bytes is a far from trivial task.  You should really be spending a few thousand dollars on a hardware card if you really must go down that route.  Even the crypto quality C# RNG is not up to generating that sort of volume of true random data.  It can generate a short key securely enough, but does not have enough entropy input to generate large quantities of true random data.  As soon as the entropy runs out, its output reverts to pseudo-random and you no longer have a One Time Pad.

As @owlstead said, use AES, in either CBC or CTR mode.  That is secure, easily available and is not designed by an amateur.